# Which is more efficient in SVG, multiple small paths or one giant one?

Tags: svg

If I am displaying a regular SVG in a browser (either as an independent file or embedded in HTML), is there any theoretical difference in efficiency between having lots of separate path elements and one giant path element?

I'm thinking of doing some kind of animation from one picture into a totally different picture. If I can draw them both with just the one `<path>` tag each, animating between them will be much easier. I am however worried that if the path is too large, the processing might take longer or be less efficient.

I have not tested this myself because it would require concatenating a lot of paths by hand, which I don't want to waste time on if it turns out to be hideously inefficient in the end :-(

Cannot seem to find anything in the docs on this, either at W3C or Mozilla. Any comments appreciated.

Comment: Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark, then post your results as an answer ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah... After reading Nick Bastin's answer I'm going to just go ahead and implement it, and test how much it differs. I was just hoping someone would be able to say *"Oh yeah, long path parsing is notoriously slower/faster than multiple short path parsing; everyone who's anyone knows that!"*

Comment: I intuitively would use a giant one. @JanDvorak: even just taking elapsed times on a specified platform it's going to be a daunting task. Maybe some tool from MDN or goggle code could help. Any hint ?

Comment: @CapelliC most likely http://jsperf.com can help here

Comment: @JanDvorak: thanks! I hope it will be useful even with *non* JS stuff, like SVG

Comment: @JanDvorak Man, thanks for the jsperf link! First time I've seen it, but I'm already thinking of a bunch of things I can use it for. And it'll probably prevent me from asking this kind of question again without a better reason than being slightly lazy... ;)

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh you can still come after running the test if you encounter some unexpected results ;-)

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh, did you perform any benchmarks eventually? It would be nice if you could publish results.

Comment: I did, and it turned out that in most cases the difference was negligible. One long path was IIRC slightly less memory-intensive. Will try to dig out the data and publish it at some point, but I'm onto something else now so it may be a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do it by hand, it's trivial to test this with a small xml parser (make up some toy data if you have to).

That being said, in a reasonable world without completely exotic optimization (where small paths ended on the same point would become a single long path), long paths are better - but probably only by a few bytes.  Rendering performance shouldn't really differ - any smart renderer is going to use the proper primitives such that the graphics card can render individual segments in parallel.

You can certainly find bad parsers and renderers, so really the question for you is going to come down to a few components:

1. Do you have control over what parser/renderer your customers use?
2. Is that faster with long or short paths?

If you can't control what your clients are using then you're going to have to build a set of test data and test on every common permutation regardless of what we say here.

Comment: `you're going to have to [...] test [...] regardless of what we say here` :-/ I had a feeling that might be the case. Incidentally, the reason I need to do it by hand is because the paths are from several distinct sources, otherwise I'd just built a simple parser as you suggest. Thanks to your answer, though, I'm at least more confident that any difference will likely be negligible. The opportunity cost of testing it doesn't seem so high now. Cheers!

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh Well, I just mean for the purposes of testing you can fake up some data and stitch/unstitch the paths with a simple parser.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but answering in case it helps others:

The following plots a line of 1000 random coordinates, 1st as a single path and 2nd as multiple separate paths.

I know it is not very rigorous as a benchmark but it results in **~10x slower performance for enter() of the multiple paths** on Chrome 84.

```js
const pathSingle = [
  [0, 0]
];
const pathMultiple = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  const pathSingleLength = pathSingle.push([
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 200),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 200),
  ]);

  pathMultiple.push([
    pathSingle[pathSingleLength - 2],
    pathSingle[pathSingleLength - 1]
  ]);
}

const svg1 = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 200);

const line = d3.line();

console.time('single');
svg1
  .selectAll('path')
  .data([{
    path: pathSingle,
  }])
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d => line(d.path));
console.timeEnd('single');

const svg2 = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 200);

console.time('multiple');
svg2
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(pathMultiple)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d => line(d));
console.timeEnd('multiple');
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.js"></script>
```